# Bind user defaults to different identifier

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, bundle, nsuserdefaults

I have a preference pane bundle (it runs in the System Preferences). I designed the interface using Interface Builder where I binded a "start automatically" checkbox to the Shared User Defaults. This works great but it writes the preference to com.apple.systempreferences. I would like to keep my preferences in the com.example.mybundle defaults. How do I do this?

I suppose I need to add a User Defaults controller in Interface Builder but how can I tell it to map with com.example.mybundle?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to bind to an NSDictionaryController whose persistence is managed through `-[NSUserDefaults persistentDomainForName:]` and `-[NSUserDefaults setPersistentDomain:forName:]` although it's frankly just as easy to use `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]` and `-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]`.